# Understanding ordnance grid reference such as TQ38-7152-9751?

Tags: coordinate-system, united-kingdom, ordnance-survey

I have a list of OS grid references, such as TQ38-7152-9751, which I assume is at a resolution level below 1km, but cannot find a grid for this or a way of converting to eastings and northings?

Comment: All this is available from Ordnance Survey https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/resources/maps-and-geographic-resources/the-national-grid.html your TQ38-7152-9751, will be  538715mE,129751mN or 51°03′01.31″N, 000°01′20.48″W (51.050328, -0.022356)

Comment: For Conversion use http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html

Comment: Where did you expect TQ38-7152-9751 to be? Somewhere between London and the English Channel?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a rather uncommon form of 1m-resolution OS grid coordinates. Here is my interpretation:

The first letter, the **T**, represents a 500km by 500km square in SE England.

The second letter, the **Q**, represents a 100km by 100km square within that (approx. London and and Sussex).

The next two digits, the **38**, represents a 10km by 10km square within that.

The next 8 digits -- a pair of 4-digit coordinates -- represent 1m resolution Eastings and Northings within that.

*Warning*

The online tool at Moveable Type, below, doesn't seem to interpret your example in the same way; it seems to interpret them not as 
**TQ38 7152 9751** (how you present them)
but as
**TQ 38715 29751**
which is a pair of 5-digit 1m-resolution coordinates within the TQ square.

The two are completely different interpretaions. Are you sure your digit groupings are as you present them?

See

- [gis.stackexchange Eastings/Northings OSGB36 Grid origin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/86816/3195)
- [wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid#Grid_letters)
- [ordnancesurvey.co.uk/resources/maps-and-geographic-resources/the-national-grid](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/resources/maps-and-geographic-resources/the-national-grid.html)
- [movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-gridref.html).